# What is the difference between CouchDB and Lotus Notes?

Tags: database, couchdb, lotus-notes

I was looking into the possibility of using CouchDB.  I heard that it was similar to Lotus Notes which everyone loves to hate.   Is this true?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Development of Lotus Notes began over 20 years ago, with [version 1 released in 1989](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-NDHistory/).  It was developed by Ray Ozzie, currently Chief Software Architect for Microsoft.

Lotus Notes (the client) and Domino (the server) have been around for a long time and are mature well featured products.  It has:

- A full client server stack with rapid application design and deployment of document oriented databases.
- A full public key infrastructure for security and encryption.
- A robust replication model and active active clustering across heterogeneous platforms (someone once showed a domino cluster with an [xbox and a huge AIX server](http://www.nashcom.de/nshweb/pages/xbox.htm)).
- A built in native directory for managing users that can also be accessed over LDAP.
- A built in native mail system that can scale to manage millions of users with multi GB mail files, with live server access or replicated locally for off-line access.  This can interface with standard internet mail through SMTP and also has POP and IMAP access built in.  The mail infrastructure is a core feature that is available to all applications built on Notes Domino (any document in a database can be mailed to any other database with a simple doc.send() command).
- A built in HTTP stack that allows server hosted databases to be accessed over the web.
- A host of integration options for accessing, transferring and interoperating with RDBMS and ERP systems, with a closely coupled integration with DB2 available allowing Notes databases to be backed by a relational store where desired.

Backwards compatibility has always been a strong feature of Notes Domino and it is not uncommon to find databases that were developed for version 3 running flawlessly in the most up to date versions.  IBM puts a huge amount of effort into this and it has a large bearing on how the product currently operates.

-

CouchDB was created by Damien Katz, starting development in 2004.  He had previously worked for IBM on Notes Domino, developing templates and eventually completely rewriting one of the core features, the formula engine, for ND6.

CouchDB shares a basic concept of a document oriented database with views that Notes Domino has.

In this model "documents" are just arbitrary collections of values that are stored some how.  In CouchDB the documents are JSON objects of arbitrary complexity.  In Notes the values are simple name value pairs, where the values can be strings, numbers, dates or arrays of those.

Views are indexes of the documents in the database, displaying certain value, calculating others and excluding undesired docs.  Once the index is build they are incrementally updated when any document in the database changes (created updated or deleted).

In CouchDB views are build by running a mapping function on each document in the database.  The mapping function calls an emit method with a JSON object for every index entry it wants to create for the given document.  This JSON object can be arbitrarily complex.  CouchDB can then run a second reducing function on the mapped index of the view.

In Notes Domino views are built by running a select function (written in Notes Domino formula language) on each document in the database.  The select function simply defines if the document should be in the view or not.  Notes Domino view design also defines a number of columns for the view.  Each column has a formula that is run against the selected document to determine the value for that column.

CouchDB is able to produce much more sophisticated view indexes than Notes Domino can.

CouchDB also has a replication system.

-

**Summary** ( ***TL;DR*** ) :  CouchDB is brand new software that is developing a core that has a similar conceptual but far more sophisticated design to that used in Lotus Notes Domino.  Lotus Notes Domino is a mature fully featured product that is capable of being deployed today.  CouchDB is starting from scratch, building a solid foundation for future feature development.  Lotus Notes Domino is continuing to develop new features, but is doing so on a 20 year old platform that strives to maintain backwards compatibility.  There are features in Notes Domino that you might wish were in CouchDB, but there are also features in Notes Domino that are anachronistic in today's world.

Answer (score 10):

It is the Notes application and UI that people usually hates. Not the architecture behind.

Answer (score 6):

Damien Katz worked at Iris (Lotus), but he was not the guy behind the Notes Database.  He is well-known in the Lotus Notes community for redesigning the [Notes Formula Engine](http://damienkatz.net/2005/01/formula-engine-rewrite.html).
There are definitely some similarities between CouchDB and Lotus Notes, such as their document-oriented, non-relational data, and replication capabilities, but they are more disparate than similar.  CouchDB is a database server and Lotus Notes is an enterprise-level collaboration platform.

Answer (score 5):

@Lex, You should prehaps say what version of Notes/Domino you are working on because your comments are incorrect.

"No transaction support" - Domino has transactional logging. If you want more complex transaction logging that is also available within coding.

"not well suited for handling multiple data transactions" - Actually it handles them just fine. You have document locking and replication conflict resolution. Depends a lot on how you set up your application to handle workflow.

"No separation between production/dev environments." - False. The only way this could be true is if you had a badly deployed environment. Developers normally should have 0 access to deploy design changes to the production environment. They would work off a template which does not replicate to main servers. Once updates are done and approved then the administrator deploys it. They do this by taking the template and signing it with a controlled signature allowed to run on production, then drop the template in and update the design of the related applications.

"The more data lotus notes contains, the more views will likely get created" - This comment makes absolutly no sense what-so-ever. I don't believe you have used Notes/Domino in any professional ability.

"lotus script is not object oriented" - Yes you make good points there. However it doesn't mean that the language is flawed. Also they have made a large number of improvements since 8.x and with 8.5.1. For example built in web services support (point to WSDL and LS code is made for you). 8.5.1 Also has a lot of new designer features like Code Templates, auto-completion, LSDoc popup help on your own functions, etc.

You also only touch on LotusScript. Yet you can also code in: 
Java, SSJS/DOJO (XPages), Javascript, @Formula language, Web Services (SOAP/REST), C-API, Eclipse Plugins(RCP). Output in JSON as well as XML.

8.5.1 Designer client is now free to download if you want to test it out.

So while I believe I am not in a position to comment on CouchDb you most certainly are not on Notes/Domino.

Comment: I found Lex's comment that "the more data you have, the more complicated handling the data is" to be comical. In what system that gets incredibly large and complex do you not get complexity?

Comment: "lotus script is not object oriented" 
You can absolutely write object-oriented code in Lotusscript. I have blogged about it numerous times over the last 15 years or so. 
Here is one article, with links to additional code samples: http://blog.texasswede.com/how-to-write-better-code-in-domino-designer-part-4/

Comment: You are commenting on a 13 year old post that is responding to a post that was deleted. I’m quoting the other post referenced text where they made a list of issues with LS. Not implying there is no OO. If there is anything wrong with this post is perhaps it should not have been posted as a response to another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes client/Domino server is comprised of an object("document")-storage (not relational) mechanism, has fully integrated certificate-based security model / user management and conflict-resolution for syncing offline/online changes to data - it's a platform for distributed applications.

"[CouchDB](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#what_is_couchdb) is a document-oriented, Non-Relational Database Management Server (NRDBMS)."

CouchDB is accessible via a REST style API.

Answer (score 1):

There's a podcast interview with Jan Lehnardt of the CouchDB team [here](http://twit.tv/floss36).

Without going back and listening to it again, I believe that Damien Katz, who was the initiator and is still the lead developer on CouchDB was also the guy behind the Notes database. So there's a sense in which CouchDB is a better Notes DB, I guess. He explains some of the differences in [his blog](http://damienkatz.net/2008/01/faq_about_couch.html).

Comment: Katz may have been one of the guys working on Notes at one time but I don't think he designed Notes when it was first created.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to how Notes deals with data in that everything is a document of arbitrary structure, and you have views over those documents instead of tables and records like you'd have in a relational database. The replication etc also has some similarities.

There isn't anything wrong with the Notes server architecture, people don't hate that so much. It's more the implementation and bloat that comes with Notes.

CouchDB has no front end either, just a server component. The Notes client sucks, and that is what people REALLY hate. Have you ever tried to email *uh I mean "memo"* something from Notes? Not pleasant :(

Comment: CouchDB does include a browser-based GUI but it's pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing Apples & Oranges

Lotus Notes Domino hasn't changed much and there is not a NoSQL service option on-prem or cloud for Notes Domino v12 or any earlier version.  Domino is not cloud based tech.

When it comes to NoSQL, Domino uses NoSQL for its own application solutions built in Domino.  There was an attempt with Domino Access Services which is based on Java 6, Rest API still uses Vectors in v12.  This service is ok, not robust, it provided a way to interface with data in a NSF.  Remember, Domino is key value pairs storage and very slow on large data sets because of the security model, each document is checked for readers and authors with every search to identify if the document can be viewed by the user.  Domino is still Web 1.0.

With CouchDB one can build app on mobile and deploy it.  There is no way to do the same with Notes/Domino because of the Domino Server.  Domino dev also only supports MS Windows and the IDE is based on older versions of Eclipse, to this day v12, there is no way to use dual monitors with the Domino IDE.  Ask any Domino Developer, they hate being forced to use a IDE on a specific platform that cannot keep up with industry.

Couch has gone through many changes as well, brief history:

- CouchDB started by Damian Katz, IBM Lotus Domino engineer
- Apache project BigCouch is born ; scalability and clustering added
- Cloudant is born ; BigData and IBM funding and IBM Cloud offering
- CouchDB 2.0 is born; Cloudant + BigData merged back into CouchDB
- CouchDB 3.0 is born; Enhanced security and prep for Foundation DB
- CouchDB 4.0 is born; architecture changed to Apples Foundation DB

https://www.dataengineeringpodcast.com/couchdb-document-database-episode-124/